# a method for converting an ArrayList into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Here I have

```
class x{
    ArrayList<Double> values;
    x() {
        values= new ArrayList<Double>();
    }
```

//here I want to write a method to convert my arraylis(values) in class(x) into an array to be able to use it in my program. Is there any way to do that. thx for your help.

```
public double [] getarray(){

}
```

Comment: Read this [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T\[\]%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to turn an ArrayList to an array, but if you do, here's how.

```
public double [] getArray(){
    double[] array = new double[values.size()];
    for(int i =0;i<values.size();i++)
    {
        array[i] = values.get(i) != null ?values.get(i):  0.0;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, just use `ArrayList.toArray()` ;)

Comment: .toArray() doesn't convert an ArrayList of Double into an array of the primitive double type.

Comment: Ouch! You're right. Maybe a Double[] is equally useful for the OP, though.

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` if any of the elements is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array list have a toArray() method. Try using that one like:

```
public double [] getarray(){
    return values.toArray();
}
```

Comment: @user1348759 What do you mean "it does not work"? It _does_ work.

Comment: It's true `toArray()` doesn't convert to an array of `double[]`. But it does convert to `Double[]`, is that useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) (see: [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Double%5b%5d%29)):

```
final ArrayList<Double> objList = new ArrayList<Double>();
final Double[] objArray = objList.toArray(new Double[objList.size()]);
final double[] primArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(objArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is converting it to a primitive `double[]`, and you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), then [`double[] Doubles.toArray(Collection<Double>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29) does the job just fine.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)